# Best way to mark an inherited class as NOT serializable

Tags: java

If I inherit from a class that is serializable but I specifically do not want my class to be serializable; what's the best way to strictly prevent serialization?

If there was a method in java.io.Serializable maybe I could throw an exception, but Serializable is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)

> Serialization of an object can be prevented by implementing writeObject and readObject methods that throw the NotSerializableException. The exception will be caught by the ObjectOutputStream and abort the serialization process.

Comment: Should I mark readObject and writeObject with a throws NotSerializableException? The private scope of these methods confuses me.

Comment: (a) No you shouldn't. You should declare it to throw IOException as per its specification. NotSeralizableException extends IOException.

(b) It does 'matter much.' If the method isn't private, serialization won't call it. This is a security measure.

Comment: And `writeObjectNoData`. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html I'd add `serialPersistenctField` (spelt correctly) containing `{ null }` to stop the serialisation mechanism even looking at it (the current implementation, anyway).

Comment: @Tom Hawtin did you mean readObjectNoData? And how exactly does one add serialPersistenceField?